# .NET P/Invoke clarification for DllImportAttribute.Value Property

Tags: .net, pinvoke, dllimport

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.dllimportattribute.value.aspx) says

> If you provide no path, the DLL must be in the current path at run
>   time

Does this mean the current executing directory or one of the directories listed in the system PATH environment variable?

TIA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither.  Windows must be able to locate the DLL through one of the following means:

- the same directory as your EXE
- the directory specified in SetDllDirectory(), if used
- the system directory (c:\windows\system32 by default)
- the 16-bit system directory (c:\windows\system by default)
- the current default directory (Environment.CurrentDirectory)
- one of the directories listed in the PATH environment variable

You should highly favor the first one and fallback to the second.

Comment: Great, thanks and to add, c:\windows\syswow64 for 64 bit machines? I am trying to understand how this all works within a WCF environment where the service uses native DLLs. In this case, these natives are not loaded from same directory as service libs and therefore are loaded from system32 or syswow64 depending on architcture. Is this correct?

Comment: That's automatic, a 32-bit process gets redirected to syswow64 instead of system32.

Comment: On a 64 bit OS, SysWow64 contains 32 bit dlls. They're for 32 bit exes. System32 contains the 64 bit dlls. Backwards, but it works. And since a 64 bit exe can't load a 32 bit dll, and conversely a 32 bit exe can't load a 64 bit dll, the path won't include the other.